# In reactive forms of angular, why the parameter passed in formControlName is passed as a string?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am creating a reactive form in angular. To synchronize the FormControl object from your typescript file to control of form in html file, you need to use formControlName directive. This is done as follows:

```
formControlName="xyz"
```

where xyz is the key of FormControl object defined in typescript file.
But in this case, xyz is treated as a string and will not get evaluated. So my doubt is that, since xyz is a key to FormControl object, so it should be evaluated and must used with square brackets like

```
[formControlName]="xyz"
```

I am satisfied with the way FormGroup is used because it is used with square brackets like:

```
[FormGroup] = "abc"
```

where abc is an object reference to FormGroup object defined in typescript file of the component.

So please explain why formControlName is not used with a square bracket?

Comment: Based on formControlName key, It will look for associated formControl directive Object in parent FormGroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is not limited for `formControlName` but for all angular input/attribute properties. It boils down to what you wanted to achieve and how your angular style guide is defined.

> **1. With brackets []:** When you expect angular to evaluate the input passed to `formControlName` use `[]`. In the below example
>   angular will treat `name` as a property of your typescript class and
>   resolve for its value.  Eg: `[formControlName] = "name"`
>
> **2. Without brackets:** When you expect angular to pass the value just as string to `formControlName` you dont use `[]`. In the below example `name` is string
>   also states you are sure that the name of the formcontrol doesn't
>   change dynamically.  Eg: `formControlName = "name"`