# Is there a convention for using Angular brackets binding notation for @Input properties?

Tags: angular, angular2-styleguide

Binding **a plain string value** to a component's `@Input` property in `Angular` can be done in either of the two ways:

```html
<my-component inputProperty="my-property-value"></my-component>
```

or:

```html
<my-component [inputProperty]="'my-property-value'"></my-component>
```

Is one of them generally preferred over the other? (Are there exceptions?)
Is there a general convention regarding this?
Is this addressed in any Angular style guide (couldn't find anything in the [official style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)).

Comment: Check my answer with example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262752/in-reactive-forms-of-angular-why-the-parameter-passed-in-formcontrolname-is-pas/58263869#58263869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [One-time string initialization](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#one-time-string-initialization) in the Angular docs:

> You should omit the brackets when all of the following are true:
>
> 1. The target property accepts a string value.
> 2. The string is a fixed value that you can put directly into the template.
> 3. This initial value never changes.

Comment: hi, but for better performance I recommend using ```@Attribute``` instead of a ```@Input```
https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-attribute-decorator-in-angular-4f7c9fb61243